# Cyclotomic polynomial identity proof with primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation, cyclotomic-polynomials

> If p is prime, show that $\Phi_{p}(x^{p^{k-1}})=\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)$.

Here is my attempt:

$x^{p^{k}}-1=\prod_{d|p^{k}}\Phi_{d}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\Phi_{p^{i}}(x)=\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)(\Phi_{p}\Phi_{p^{2}}\cdots \Phi_{p^{k-1}})=(x^{p^{k-1}})^{p}-1=(x^{p^{k-1}}-1)\Phi_{p}(x^{p^{k-1}})$

But how do I show that $x^{p^{k-1}}-1=\Phi_{p}\Phi_{p^{2}}\cdots \Phi_{p^{k-1}}$?

Comment: In this product you omitted a factor $\Phi_1(x)$. In fact, $x^{p^k}-1=\Phi_1(x)\Phi_p(x)\Phi_{p^2}(x)\cdots\Phi_{p^k}(x)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oops, that is totally my bad. Then it is just by definition (?) that they are equal (of course when I include the factor $\Phi_{1}$...!)

Comment: What is your definition of $\Phi_n(x)$? My definition is that it is the minimal polynomial of a primitive $n$th root of unity. By standard Galois theory, one can show the roots of $\Phi_n(x)$ are precisely all of the primitive $n$th roots, and therefore $x^n-1$ is $\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x)$ since both are monic and have the exact same set of (distinct) roots.